# Unresolved reference in defined function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to call a function that I defined in the code, however, it's saying that it's not defined?  The error is where I have "add_to()" it's saying it's not defined.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
grocery_list = ['salmon', 'beef', 'eggs', 'milk']

print(grocery_list)
question = input("Would you like to add anything to the list?: ")
if question == "yes" or "y" or "Y":
    add_to()
else:
    print("Enjoy your shopping")


def add_to():
    input("Please enter the item you'd like to add: ")
    grocery_list.append(str(input))


print(grocery_list)
```

Comment: Put the definition of `add_to` at the top.

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid.  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did function declaration after the function call. Please follow :[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more information and secondly if take any input from user, you need to store in some variable to use any way. Here is the code that add item perfectly.

```
grocery_list = ['salmon', 'beef', 'eggs', 'milk']

def add_to():
    s= input("Please enter the item you'd like to add: \n")
    grocery_list.append(str(s))

print(grocery_list)
question = input("Would you like to add anything to the list?: \n")
if question == "yes" or "y" or "Y":
    add_to()
else:
    print("Enjoy your shopping")



print(grocery_list)
```

Output :

```
['salmon', 'beef', 'eggs', 'milk']
Would you like to add anything to the list?:
yes
Please enter the item you'd like to add: 
yourhead
['salmon', 'beef', 'eggs', 'milk', 'yourhead']
```

Comment: That's another thing I wasn't struggling to figure out.  Thank you!  Can you explain why I need to add the (str part?  Also what's the point of using \n to start a new line when I don't need a new line?  Is it just good in practice?

Comment: Had to wait to be able to do it.  Just did both, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Okay `\n` is for good code readability. You need to give `\n` with `input()` and lets say in future if their is more confusing input user is giving which is long input and mixture of string and int, then you have to give `\n`

Comment: Okay and the point of (str) is just to let it know that they are inputting text and that it can only be text, correct?

Comment: Its depend on developer(you), whether in which form you want to grab input from the user whether in form of int, float, string..etc